# Ho to remove rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms

Tags: wireless

I have a problem with this driver rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms it does not work.

I would like to remove it, not fix it, remove. I'd be grateful to anyone providing help. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to remove it? `sudo apt-get remove --purge NAME-OF-PACKAGE`

Comment: Yes, I tried this: sudo apt-get remove rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms

(Reading database ... 341608 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms (1.6) ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.6
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `dpkg -r` command.

Syntax:

```
sudo dpkg -r [PACKAGE NAME]
```

Here :

```
sudo dpkg -r rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms
```